# Default .htaccess rewrite block for EE in a subfolder?

Tags: htaccess, config, 404

**Is there a default .htaccess rewrite block for EE while running it in a subfolder?**

I have EE in /eefolder/ i.e., mydomain.com/eefolder/  with simply

`RewriteEngine on`

in the .htaccess file in that folder.

I have WordPress in root, i.e. mydomain.com with its own .htaccess file and rewrite block.

When I try to view any URL in EE, such as mydomain.com/eefolder/site , I get a 404 from either WordPress or the default 404 from the hosting service.

What do I need in .htaccess in the eefolder? Is there a default rewrite block? I have the index.php file in the eefolder.

Or is there another configuration to change to be able to view the EE site and not get a 404?

Comment: I run versions of EE in sub domains without issue. Can you create a sub domain? eesite.mydomain.com

Comment: Good idea, but the answer below works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the standard method and add in your subfolder name before `index.php` in the RewriteRule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /SUBFOLDER/index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But now, hah, I'm stuck with "This site is currently offline" message that I can't seem to disable.